# Virtual template specialization overriding?

Tags: c++, templates

You have a resource manager here:

```
enum class type {
    bitmap, sound, font
};

class manager {
public:
    virtual ~manager() = default;
    
    template<type t, typename RET>
    RET get(string_view id);
};
```

You want the `get` method to return different types of resources

So you specialize them inside `manager` class:

```
template<>
bitmap get<type::bitmap, bitmap>(string_view id);

template<>
sound get<type::sound, sound>(string_view id);

template<>
font get<type::font, font>(string_view id);
```

But the `manager` is an abstract class, you actually use instances like `manager_local`, `manager_http`...

And those derived classes need to override the base methods.

So the base `get` should be `virtual`

```
template<>
virtual bitmap get<type::bitmap, bitmap>(string_view id);

template<>
virtual sound get<type::sound, sound>(string_view id);

template<>
virtual font get<type::font, font>(string_view id);
```

But how to declare the derived classes?

Those bunch of code don't work

```
class manager1 : public manager {
public:
    template<> // compile error here
    bitmap get<type::bitmap, bitmap>(string_view id) {...}
};
```

You cannot define `get` as pure virtual function, too

Comment: The templated `get` should be non-virtual and forward to a virtual non-template function.  `template<>
bitmap fetch<type::bitmap, bitmap>(string_view id) { return get_bitmap(id);} virtual bitmap get_bitmap(string_view id) = 0;` Derived classes override `get_bitmap`.

Comment: `fetch` <-> `get`?

Comment: How about `get_bitmap`/`get_sound`/`get_font`?

Comment: So the big question is: why are you making life hard on yourself and using templates here? Why use inheritance at all?

Comment: I want the `get_*` functions to have the same name, but function overloading doesn't work since they have the same parameter list

Comment: And what if you have a `bytebuf` class containing `read_int`, `read_short`, `read_char`, `read_long`...? Is this better than `template<> int read<int>`, `read<short>`, `read<char>`?